# How to make eclipse wizard acts like tree with its pages?

Tags: swt, jface

As I know all Eclipse wizards has linear navigation in this method if Wizard class:

```java
@Override
public void addPages() {
    addPage(wizard class);
}
```

but at the first wizard page I would like to manage the next page. I have enum class at my `WizardPage`:

```java
enum SELECTED_ACTION {
        CREATE, LOAD_LOCAL, LOAD_REMOTE
    }

    SELECTED_ACTION action;
```

and then I try to override next page method:

```java
  @Override
 public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
IWizardPage nextPage = super.getNextPage();
if (nextPage == null) {
    if (action != null && action == action.LOAD_REMOTE) {
        nextPage = new RemotePage("");
    }

    if (action != null && action == action.CREATE) {
        nextPage = new TestWixzard();
    }
}
return nextPage;
}
```

with previously added pages:

```java
@Override
    public void addPages() {
        startPage = new ActionPage("some title");

        addPage(new ActionPage(""));
        addPage(new RemotePage(""));
        addPage(new TestWixzard());
    }
```

but I usually move after `ActionPage` to `RemotePage` without taking into account which action I did on the `ActionPage`. Maybe I did smth wrong, because when I remove at all two next pages I don't see any next button so it is wrong I think. Change action type I can in the ActionPage:

```java
@Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        container.setLayout(layout);
        Group group = new Group(container, SWT.BORDER);
        group.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).create());

        Button local = new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
        local.setText(Messages.SelectSolutionDialog_btn_continue_text);
        local.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                switch (e.type) {
                case SWT.Selection:
                    action = SELECTED_ACTION.LOAD_LOCAL;
                    getContainer().updateButtons();
                }
            }
        });
        Button load = new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
        load.setText(Messages.SelectSolutionDialog_btn_load_text);
        load.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                switch (e.type) {
                case SWT.Selection:
                    action = SELECTED_ACTION.LOAD_REMOTE;
                    getContainer().updateButtons();
                }
            }
        });
        Button create = new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
        create.setText(Messages.SelectSolutionDialog_btn_new_text);
        create.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                switch (e.type) {
                case SWT.Selection:
                    action = SELECTED_ACTION.CREATE;
                    getContainer().updateButtons();
                }
            }
        });

        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to create new pages in `getNextPage`. Create all the pages in the `addPages` method and return one of those pages in `getNextPage`.

You can get an existing page with:

```java
IWizardPage page = getWizard().getPage("pageName");
```

where `pageName` is the name the constructor of the page specified.

Don't call `super.getNextPage`. Instead just determine which page you want next and return that.